# Limits for websocket connections in azure

Tags: azure, websocket

Somewhere I've read websocket clients are limited ...so what if I wanna create a simple game with 10000 users grouped by 2 or 4 players for team? it seams I ve no solution or maybe I'm watching in a wrong direction. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Free:  (5) concurrent connections per website instance

Shared: (35) concurrent connections per website instance

Standard: (350) concurrent connections per website instance

Answer (score 8):

I see this has now been changed to ([from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits)):

> Free:  (5) connections
>
> Shared: (35) connections
>
> Basic: (350) connections
>
> Standard: no limit

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense that Azure Websites have a limit on concurrent connected users. 
Are you really gonna need to support 10k of them ? it looks like you're gonna have to look elsewhere for hosting, because 10 instances of standard web sites is 3500 users max :-/

If you're using ASP.NET with signalR, you may have more luck with [Azure Web Roles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/06/27/windows-azure-websites-web-roles-and-vms-when-to-use-which.aspx) (the [service bus/signalr nuget package](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/scaleout-with-windows-azure-service-bus) makes it really easy to build scaling applications without worrying about sharing client states between your web role instances).

Comment: Thanks bedane, im a newbie in azure world, so I'm checking if it can help me to solve my problem...Maybe signalR could help me....or maybe a VM has not the same restriction....I need to get more informations. I ve read about limits in some thread but not in official documentation of microsoft...how 's possibile they dont'declare the tech limits? :|